# Removing sequential repeating items from List<T> using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a way to prevent repeating items in a list but still preserve the order. 
For example

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4
```

should become

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I've done it quite inelegantly using a `for` loop, checking the next item as follows

```
    public static List<T> RemoveSequencialRepeats<T>(List<T> input) 
    {
        var result = new List<T>();

        for (int index = 0; index < input.Count; index++)
        {
            if (index == input.Count - 1)
            {
                result.Add(input[index]);
            }
            else if (!input[index].Equals(input[index + 1]))
            {
                result.Add(input[index]);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, preferably with LINQ?

Comment: Why do you think that your solution is inelegant?

Comment: Seconded. LINQ is good when you don't need to consider an item in relation to those around it. When you do, it can be more clear and straightforward to write good old imperative code.

Comment: @nawfal This isn't actually a duplicate, the other question is how to _identify_ sequential repeats. This question asks how to _remove_ sequential repeats from a list.

Comment: @Dennis depending on the size of your input, there could be memory thrashing implications. `List<T>.Add` by its nature can be very GC intensive...

Answer (score 12):

You can create extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveSequentialRepeats<T>(
      this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var current = iterator.Current;
        yield return current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(iterator.Current, current))
                continue;

            current = iterator.Current;
            yield return current;
        }
    }        
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = items.RemoveSequentialRepeats().ToList();
```

Comment: You could create an overload for that which allows a custom comparer to be specified too.

Comment: @TrevorPilley agree with you. We will leave it for OP for simplicity :) Actually my first thought was to create class `NoSequentialRepeatsIterator` to avoid duplication of code - assignment to current (that will be moved to field of class) and returning it

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this isn't written as a simple `foreach`?

Comment: @Alxandr in that case you will need logic to determine if something was returned on first iteration - you can't simply compare with `default(T)`, boolean flag will be required, which will be checked on each iteration

Comment: Yeah, but it's a simple boolean. I recon you're code would be shrinked to about... 5 lines? Though you'd get the penalty of having the boolean check on every itteration.... Maybe your code's actually better ^^

Comment: Is there some downvoter which can explain reason of downvoting?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky this is also executed (almost) every loop: `comparer.Equals(iterator.Current, current)`? I don't see much difference between your code and a normal `foreach`.

Comment: @KingKing - this is normal `foreach`, just special casing first element. Also shows how to use `Equals` for generic version of comparison that can work for all types.

Comment: @KingKing normal foreach also should compare items with previously returned. How you are going to do that?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky a variable to save the previously returned value would be OK, the answer of `Roman Pekar` is something like that but it's not a 1-line LINQ solution. This problem can be solved OK without LINQ.

Comment: @KingKing consider of list of strings with `null` inside. Then try to use Pekar's answer. BTW where you have found LINQ in my solution?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky you are using the core stuff of LINQ which uses `GetEnumerator` and `yield`, however the last statement of last comment of mine didn't talk about your solution, there are many solutions (of others including me) here using `LINQ`

Comment: @KingKing LINQ also uses delegates, but delegates are not LINQ :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yes, I missed that (BTW lambda is the preferred style):)

Comment: The Microsoft Interactive Framework (sister of the Reactive Framework) has the method `DistinctUntilChanged` that comes out of the box that does what you want.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use pure `LINQ`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4};
var result = list.Where((x, i) => i == 0 || x != list[i - 1]);
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if so your first comment should have been `This would not work for IEnumrable...`, however we can use `Cast<>` or `OfType<>` before using `Where` and `ElementAt`

Comment: You can remove the `(i > 0)&&`-part; the check is redundant.

Comment: @DominicKexel I'm not sure, I thought the 2 conditions are also checked, it looks like that only the first is checked if it's true (some kind of `Or` not `OrAlso` in VB). Thank you!

Comment: @KingKing Yes, the [`||` operator uses short-circut evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.71).aspx): *The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.*

Comment: @RomanPekar I'm not sure about the inner implementation of `ElementAt` however I think it's fast because the use of `index`, if the original source is an array, we can pass the index directly without using `ElementAt` and that would be fast for sure. Thanks for vote up.

Comment: I think it's constant, don't have reflector to see, but anyway, you could use `l.Where((x, i) => i == 0 || x != l[i - 1])`

Comment: @RomanPekar thanks, I forgot about the use of indexer in `List`

Answer (score 4):

you could write simple LINQ :

```
var l = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 };
var k = new Nullable<int>();
var nl = l.Where(x => { var res = x != k; k = x; return res; }).ToArray();

int[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

or pythonic (well, my best try) way:

```
l.Zip(l.Skip(1), (x, y) => new[] { x, y })
   .Where(z => z[0] != z[1]).Select(a => a[0])
   .Concat(new[] { l[l.Length - 1] }).ToArray()

int[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

the simplest one (**edit:** haven't seen that it already suggested by [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17988250/1744834))

```
l.Where((x, i) => i == l.Length - 1 || x != l[i + 1]).ToArray()
int[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

Comment: this is not simple because it uses an extra mutable variable

Comment: @SargeBorsch agreed, check my third solution

Answer (score 4):

If you really really hate the world, pure LINQ:

```
var nmbs = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 };
var res = nmbs
              .Take(1)
              .Concat(
                      nmbs.Skip(1)
                          .Zip(nmbs, (p, q) => new { prev = q, curr = p })
                          .Where(p => p.prev != p.curr)
                          .Select(p => p.curr));
```

But note that you'll need to enumerate (at least partially) the enumerable 3 times (the `Take`, the "left" part of `Zip`, the first parameters of `Zip`). **This method is slower than building a `yield` method or doing it directly**.

Explanation:

- You take the first number (`.Take(1)`)
- You take all the numbers from the second (`.Skip(1)`) and pair it with all the numbers (`.Zip(nmbs`). We will call `curr` the numbers from the first "collection" and `prev` the numbers from the second "collection" (`(p, q) => new { prev = q, curr = p })`). You then take only the numbers that are different from the previous number (`.Where(p => p.prev != p.curr)`) and from these you take the `curr` value and discard the `prev` value (`.Select(p => p.curr)`)
- You concat these two collections (`.Concat(`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want LINQ statement that do not rely on captured value of result inside the call you'll need some construct with aggregate as it is the only method that carries value along with operation. I.e. based on Zaheer Ahmed's code:

```
array.Aggregate(new List<string>(), 
     (items, element) => 
     {
        if (items.Count == 0 || items.Last() != element)
        {
            items.Add(element);
        }
        return items;
     });
```

Or you can even try to build list without `if`:

```
 array.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), 
    (items, element) => items.Concat(
       Enumerable.Repeat(element, 
           items.Count() == 0 || items.Last() != element ? 1:0 ))
    );
```

Note to get reasonable performance of above samples with `Aggregate` you'd need to also carry last value (`Last` will have to iterate whole sequence on each step), but code that carries 3 values `{IsEmpty, LastValue, Sequence}` in a `Tuple` is very strange looking. These samples are here for entertaining purposes only.

One more option is to `Zip` array with itself shifted by 1 and return elements that are not equal...

More practical option is to build iterator that filters values:

```
IEnumerable<string> NonRepeated(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    string last = null;
    bool lastSet = false;

    foreach(var element in values)
    {
       if (!lastSet || last != element)
       {
          yield return element;
       }
       last = element;
       lastSet = true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

check if last of new list and current item is not same then add to new list:

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
results.Add(array.First());
foreach (var element in array)
{
    if(results[results.Length - 1] != element)
        results.Add(element);
}
```

or using LINQ:

```
List<int> arr=new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 };
List<int> result = new List<int>() { arr.First() };
arr.Select(x =>
               {
                if (result[result.Length - 1] != x) result.Add(x);
                    return x;
               }).ToList();
```

Do have proper validation for null object.

Comment: +1: may be more efficient to add array.First() to the list before the loop though

Comment: No worries :) Of course it goes without saying this needs one element in the array now but I'm sure OP can handle this :P

Comment: Unless the compiler does something incredibly brilliant, this will have really bad performance on larger list. You should replace `results.Last()` (which should in general never be used unless it's absolutely necessary) with `results[results.Length - 1]`. While the second one is only a lookup of 1 variable and an offset (ie, 2 variable lookups), the first one (using `Last()`) goes through the (growing) collection for every round. If your list has 10 unique items, you itterate the first one something like 9! times.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed also, LINQ should (in general) not be used for side-effects (like you are in your second example).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 ";
        var list = input.Split(',').Select(i => i.Trim());

        var result = list
            .Select((s, i) => 
                (s != list.Skip(i + 1).FirstOrDefault()) ? s : null)
            .Where(s => s != null)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint - you can initialize array this way `int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4}` - much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

Here the code you need :

```
public static List<int> RemoveSequencialRepeats(List<int> input)
{
     var result = new List<int>();

     result.Add(input.First());
     result.AddRange(input.Where(p_element => result.Last() != p_element);
     return result;
 }
```

The LINQ magic is:

```
 result.Add(input.First());
 result.AddRange(input.Where(p_element => result.Last() != p_element);
```

Or you can create extension method like this:

```
public static class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        List<int> numList=new List<int>(){1,2,2,2,4,5,3,2};

        numList = numList.RemoveSequentialRepeats();
    }

    public static List<T> RemoveSequentialRepeats<T>(this List<T> p_input)
    {
        var result = new List<T> { p_input.First() };

        result.AddRange(p_input.Where(p_element => !result.Last().Equals(p_element)));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like referencing an F# project you can write

```
let rec dedupe = function
  | x::y::rest when x = y -> x::dedupe rest
  | x::rest -> x::dedupe rest
  | _ -> []
```