# How to remove consecutive duplicate items from a list

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, list

I have a list like:

```
  A  B B  C D D D B E D
```

I would like to remove consecutive duplicate items from a list to get

```
  A  B C D B E D
```

If I try `Distinct()`, it gives me just `A B C D E`

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over a list remember the previous element, if the current is equal to a previous, ignore it, otherwise add to a list.

Comment: This is merely a comment IMO.

Comment: @Him no it isn't. Nowhere is it specified that an answer must contain copy-pasteable code. This answer describes an alorithm that works, it's up to OP whether they want to implement it.

Comment: It's pretty much what you have to do though, good enough for me.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the question is listed in the algorithm section. It means that someone is looking for an algorithm. I gave an exact algorithm, which runs with the best complexity. I do not care that it is so short that can be described in 1 sentence, neither I want to overcomplicate it with a huge long explanation like this one which does not provide any meaning whatsoever and only written for the sake of being long and complex. So that other people would see how long it is. Also I do not like providing copypaste code if a person have not done any work by himself.

Comment: Your last comment is too verbose to be merely a comment, please revise it.

Comment: Of all the answers in here I think this is the best one. You don't need to use a freaking multiline lambda with sorting and grouping to do operations like this. A good old for-loop will do the job.

Comment: @SalvadorDali yes in both algorithms and linq section, I was searching for one line linq solution

Comment: @Ahmad because one-line Linq solutions are known for their readability, maintainability and performance, right? For some more Linq gore, see the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987909/removing-sequential-repeating-items-from-listt-using-linq).

Comment: @Ahmad then write what you have tried and why you do not like something. Also if you look for a linq solution do not add irrelevant tags like `algorithm`, `list`. This way algorithm people would not see a question and would not bother answering it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Some irony involved? Noooooo

Comment: Yes I mistook by putting `algorithm` there, however I thought a linq guru also needs an algorithm to do that. can I take back the `algorithm` now and remove it from tag list?

Comment: @Ahmad the question is already closed, so there is no point to do anything (in my opinion). Also linq is something language specific and has nothing to do with algorithms. The same way as comprehensions in python is not an algorithmic concept. If someone adds an `algorithm` tag majority of algorithm people assume that it will be enough just to outline the idea and not to implement it. For example if someone asks how to find shortest distance on a map, for me it will be enough to tell just one word: Dijkstra and not write 20 lines of code.

Comment: Okay, now I see the point, haven´t noticed the tag at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
public static void removeAdjacentDuplicates<T>(this List<T> List, IComparer<T> Comparer)
{
    int unique = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        if ((i == 0) || (Comparer.Compare(List[unique - 1], List[i]) != 0))
            List[unique++] = List[i];
    List.RemoveRange(unique, List.Count - unique);
}
```

(This is essentially what @Salvador Dali said) -
Removing in range of `unique` to `List.Count - unique` should get you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *new collection* (initial list preserved intact):

```
  // not necessary a list
  IEnumerable<String> source = "A B B C D D D B E D".Split(' ');

  String last = null;

  var result = source.Where((item, index) => {
    var value = index == 0 || item != last;
    last = item;

    return value;
  });

  // "A B C D B E D"
  Console.Write(String.Join(" ", result));
```

In case you want to remove items in the *existing list*:

```
  List<String> list = "A B B C D D D B E D".Split(' ').ToList();

  for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 1; --i)
    if (list[i] == list[i - 1])
      list.RemoveAt(i);

  // "A B C D B E D"
  Console.Write(String.Join(" ", list));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inplace.

1) Keep pointer `i` and `j` pointing in the beginning. Now increase the pointer `j` to succeeding elements until a different element in found (different from the one that `i` is pointing at).

```
A A B B B C D D
^ ^ ^
i j j //(j increasing, stopped at B)
```

2) Once a different element is found, do `arr[++i] = arr[j];`. That is, copying the new element to the next position of `i`.

```
A B B B B C D D
  ^ ^
  i j
```

3) Now restart the process by doing. And now increase the `j` as in the first step and repeat.

```
A B B B B C D D
  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
  i j j j j //(j increasing, stopped at C)
```